# Changing Layers Attributes in pyqgis

Tags: attribute-table, pyqgis-3

I am trying to change the attributes of a table in pyqgis. However, when finishing the changes, I cannot see them in the layer.

I am using QGIS 3.8.1

Here is the simple version of my code

```
layer.startEditing()
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
    attrs = { 28 : 60.5, 29 : 70.5} #Changing the values in the 
                                    #28th columns and 29th columns to 60.5 and 70.5
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeAttributeValues:
        layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ 0 : attrs}) 
        # changing the first rows values
    layer.updateFields()
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, where are you setting attrs_TMC variable?

Comment: Sorry it's attrs instead of attrs_TMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following to change the values from your specified fields:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
attrs = {28: 60.5, 29: 70.5}
feat = layer.getFeature(0)
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feat.id(): attrs})
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: It did not work as well

Comment: It worked. The problem that when assigning the values 60.5 and 70.5 through other loop, the values were not registered as float. Therefore, I included float() as a function and it worked perfect.

Comment: @Lush_coding - Glad you got it working :)